# Problem in finding max. min, sum, product don't execute 0

Tags: c

So i have an assignment is to write a program to input integers; the program ends when user inputs 0. Find max, min,  average, and product of all input numbers. Don't count 0 in min, max,sum,prod
Here is my work

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int max_value, min_value, sum_values, product_values, count;
  max_value = min_value = sum_values = product_values = count = 0;

  int number;
  while (scanf("%d", &number) == 1 && number != 0) {
    if (number == 0) {
      continue;
    }

    if (number > max_value) {
      max_value = number;
    }
    if (number < min_value) {
      min_value = number;
    }

    sum_values += number;
    product_values *= number;

    count++;
  }

  float average_value = (float) sum_values / (float) count;

  if (count > 0) {
    printf("Max value: %d\n", max_value);
    printf("Min value: %d\n", min_value);
    printf("Average value: %.2f\n", average_value);
    printf("Product value: %d\n", product_values);
  } else {
    printf("Error: No non-zero inputs\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I try it and it runs well, but the problem is the program count 0 as a number. How do i solving this

Comment: Relevant: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).

Comment: A hint: the initialization of `product_values` and `min_value` to `0` is problematic.

Comment: "the problem is the program count 0 as a number" that's not a problem I found (as long as `0` isn't supposed to be data).

Comment: Initialize `min_value = INT_MAX` and `max_value = INT_MIN`

Comment: Add `fprintf(stderr, "DEBUG: processing the number %d.\n", number);` inside the loop.

Comment: `while (scanf("%d", &number) == 1 && number != 0) {` means `if (number == 0) {` will never be reached in the loop. The `if () { ... }` block is superfluous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue I found was within the setup and usage of the "while" loop along with other variable initialization.  With that, following is a refactored version of the program to more closely provide the functionality evidently you are looking for.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    int max_value = INT_MIN, min_value = INT_MAX, sum_values = 0, product_values = 1, count = 0, number = 0;    /* Define and initialize the variables */
    float average_value = 0.0;

    while (1)
    {
        printf("Enter an integer: ");                       /* Prompt the user for an integer               */

        if(scanf("%d", &number) != 1)                       /* Validate that an entry was made              */
        {
            printf("Invalid entry - please try again\n");
            continue;
        }

        if (number == 0)                                    /* Exit the prompting loop if zero was entered  */
            break;

        if (number > max_value)
        {
            max_value = number;
        }

        if (number < min_value)
        {
            min_value = number;
        }

        sum_values += number;
        product_values *= number;                           /* Note that this could overflow the size of an integer and go negative */

        count++;
    }

    if (count > 0)
        average_value = (float) sum_values / (float) count;

    if (count > 0)
    {
        printf("Max value: %d\n", max_value);
        printf("Min value: %d\n", min_value);
        printf("Average value: %.2f\n", average_value);
        printf("Product value: %d\n", product_values);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error: No non-zero inputs\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The points to note are:

- The "limits.h" header was added to include the actual smallest and largest integer values for variable initialization.
- As noted in the good comments, the "product_values" variable needs to be initialized to a value of "1"; otherwise, the product value will always equate to a value of zero.
- The "while" loop is simplified to basically be and endless loop with testing for a zero input value being the trigger for exiting the loop.
- Additional testing of the count value to ensure that a "divide by zero" scenario does not occur.

With those refactored bits, following is a couple of tests of the program with random integer entries.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/MinMaxAvg/bin/Release$ ./MinMaxAvg 
Enter an integer: 44
Enter an integer: 599
Enter an integer: 2
Enter an integer: 736
Enter an integer: 14
Enter an integer: 3999
Enter an integer: 88
Enter an integer: 0
Max value: 3999
Min value: 2
Average value: 783.14
Product value: 119410688
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/MinMaxAvg/bin/Release$ ./MinMaxAvg 
Enter an integer: 4444444444444444
Enter an integer: 3333333333333
Enter an integer: 0
Max value: 438711637
Min value: -598358244
Average value: -79823304.00
Product value: 1356589132
```

As noted, if large enough integer values are entered, there is a possibility of the multiplication value to exceed the size limit of the integer, causing and overflow condition and possibly evaluating to a negative number.  So that is something to bear in mind.

As always, review the refactored code and also it would be beneficial to review  tutorial literature on the use of the various loops such as "while" loops.